# How can i use eclipse 2020-09 to develop java 8 projects?

Tags: java, eclipse

I am a regular IntelliJ user, but most of my co-workers use Eclipse.  A lot of them say the latest version of Eclipse "2020-09", which requires a JRE "higher than Java 8" in order to run, cannot be used to develop projects requiring JRE8.

This is pretty surprising to me, since I know it is possible to install multiple JDKs and JREs on one machine, I've done it plenty of times.

What is the typical way a person would configure Eclipse 2020-09 (already installed) to work on a project that requires a Java 8 JRE?

Comment: It's not true what they say. Eclipse requires Java 11 to run, but supports also older versions (starting with Java 1.1, up to Java 15, and of course Java 8).

Comment: You can target any Java version you want if you install the proper runtime. Just because eclipse itself requires Java 11 doesn't mean it can't compile for lower versions.

Comment: The primary answer covers the details, but the short answer is that Eclipse requires a Java11+ JDK to RUN Eclipse, but it can use other JDKs to compile code.

Answer (score 7):

JRE 8 apps in eclipse workspace is possible by having the jre 8 jdk. It is true that in order to use eclipse 2020-09 you need java 11+ jdk/jre, but making projects that support jre 8 is still possible.Even I still use 2020-06 and before. Here is a method you could use to get JRE 8 implemented back in your project. Although you can change the defaults, this one will help you change the environment back to java 8 for 1 project.

Right click the library named somthing like "JRE system library[JavaSE-11]". Press properties. This is what you will see [JRE System Library chooser image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zkahy.png)

Choose "Alternate JRE" then click "Installed JREs"[Step Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Fj37.jpg)

Press "Add" then you will see 3 options. Choose standard VM. Find your java 8 **jdk** directory. Usually it is something like C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_251.[image: DirectoryChooser]

You can configure the default arguments for your jvm runtime. Then simply hit ok,select the jdk-8 library and close it. Then choose alternate jre again and in the drop-down choose jdk-1.8.0 or some name like that. **This will only work if you also have java 8 installed alongside java 11 that is configured properly JDK**

Answer (score 1):

You can use Java 11 to start the Eclipse 2020-09 and configure a project to compile with Java 8. The problem is if you want a Eclipse plugin that uses CORBA for example. This module was removed from Java 11 earlier. In this case, I recommend to use Eclipse 2020-06.

Answer (score 0):

Earlier versions of 2020-09 was working with Java 8. I had it, too. Then I updated and I got the same error message like you.

I propose to use an older one or to install JRE 11 and set the JAVA_HOME env variable to it.

The inside the IDE you can set java 8 like an JDK and develope your project with Java 8 while eclipse is running with 11.